# I have a function and call those function in app.get()

Tags: node.js

I call getpage() inside app.get() and try to get all information when i send response

1. data:
2. success:
3. status:
4. message:

   But i get only success, status, message  but data not receive

```
   function getpage(url, cks) {
    const curl = new Curl()
    const urld = url
    console.log(urld);
    curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, urld)
    curl.setOpt(Curl.option.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
    var gh = curl.setOpt(Curl.option.COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/' + cks)
    curl.setOpt(Curl.option.FOLLOWLOCATION, true)
    console.log(gh)
    curl.on('end', function (statusCode, body, headers) {
        var result = body;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
        this.close();
    });
    curl.on('error', function (err, curlErrorCode) {
        console.error(err);
        console.error(curlErrorCode);
        this.close();
    });
    const hg = curl.perform();
}

app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
    let geturl = req.query.url;
    let getemail = req.query.email;

    res.json({
        data: getpage(geturl, getemail),
        success: true,
        status: 200,
        message: "Done"
    })
})
```

[image]

Comment: your `getpage` function is not returning anything. Return the data from the `getPage`, you will get that on the response. The return on `curl.on('end'` return the CB function not the `getPage` one.

Answer (score 0):

You're using node-libcurl to make a request but not doing anything with the data from that request. The result of `getpage()` is undefined, that function never returns anything. Modify getpage to take a callback, and use that to get your data out of the `'end'` event listener. (or look into `Fetch`, it's very convenient).

```js
function getpage(url, cks, cb) {
  const curl = new Curl()
  const urld = url
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, urld)
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/' + cks)
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.FOLLOWLOCATION, true)
  curl.on('end', function (statusCode, body, headers) {
    var result = body;
    // use your callback here!
    cb(result);
    this.close();
  });
  curl.on('error', function (err, curlErrorCode) {
    console.error(err);
    console.error(curlErrorCode);
    this.close();
  });
  curl.perform();
}

app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
  let geturl = req.query.url;
  let getemail = req.query.email;

  // call getpage and pass in a function
  // expecting the results
  getpage(geturl, getemail, (results) => {
    res.json({
      data: results,
      success: true,
      status: 200,
      message: "Done"
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: but when i console getapage(getur, getemail) in app.get() then it's console  information which is inside these function

Comment: @VishalKumar I don't understand what you "console information inside this function"